# unstripped binary or object creating debian package

Tags: dpkg, deb, debian

I'm new to package creation and I'm trying to create a .deb package and keep getting 'unstripped-binary-or-object' on all my libraries and executables.

I have everything setup in the directory tree where I want them to end up (and a DEBIAN folder with the control file) and then do

`fakeroot dpkg-deb --build ./mypackage`

when I lint with
`lintian mypackage.deb`

I get that error.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `objcopy` or `strip` from `binutils` to strip debug symbols from the binaries that you are building. I would, however, suggest that you either keep an unstripped copy of the binaries or - in case of using `objcopy` - simply split off the debug symbols into a separate file that can later be used with a debugger.

Often the `*-devel` packages come with symbols of the corresponding `*` package, by the way. So you may want to consider creating one of those in addition, if this is something you release to the general public.

For strip a common use is to only strip the debugging symbols:

```
strip -S -o [stripped-file] [input-file]
```

The switch corresponding to `strip -S` for is `objcopy -g` or simply use the long form that works for both (but not on all platforms on which I had to use `strip`): `--strip-debug`.

For the described use of splitting the debug symbols using `objcopy`, check out the option `--only-keep-debug` in `man objcopy`.

Comment: For me calling `objcopy --strip-debug` was not sufficient to please lintian. I also had to add `--strip-unneeded`: `objcopy --strip-debug --strip-unneeded`